# Using variables as function names and parameters in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following variables in my VBA logic sFunctionName, sParam1, sParam2, sParam3 all string variables populated from a table. I would like to use those variables to call a function. I have tried using Application.Run(sFunctionName, sParam1) and the statement fails, However when i use Application.Run(sFunctionName) it works just fine. I have also tried Eval on someones suggestion with no luck. Can someone let me know what I am missing, or if i can even do what I am attempting to do? I appreciate any and all help.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Have you tried it without braces?

Comment: No I did not, and that was infact the error. Once I removed the braces all went smooth. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I've added the answer to this question. You could mark it as accepted to make this question useful for others.

Comment: `Application.Run(Arg1, Arg2....)` is a function and returns a value. `Application.Run Arg1, Arg2...` is a subroutine call that doesn't return a value. So, if you use `Call Application.Run` leave out the parens. If you use `MyVariable = Application.Run` then you need to use the parens. This 100% consistent behavior across VBA and always has been.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton--That's *almost* right, but you got tripped up by one of the VB(A) weirdnesses: Yes, you call a Sub without parens on the parameters... *unless* you use the `call` keyword, in which case you *must* use the parens. I'm sure you know this already when you're not dashing off a comment, but others reading the comments may not. I'll try to find the really good article on parens in VB(A) that I read recently & *thought* I'd bookmarked....

Comment: Got it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx  It talks about VBScript, but the same applies to VBA.

Answer (score 2):

#1. Regarding **Eval()**: Per Access's help files,

> You can use the Eval function to
>   evaluate an expression that results in
>   a text string or a numeric value.

So, if your function resolves to text or numeric, then you're good to go.
i.e. `Debug.Print Eval("Date()")`

#2. I don't think your problem with **Run()** is with the actual function itself, but rather how you are applying it.  I threw together some quick code.  Does this help?

```
Function AddOne(What As Integer) As Integer
    AddOne = What + 1
End Function

Function x()
    Dim WhichFunc As String
    WhichFunc = "AddOne"
    Dim What As Integer
    What = 1
    x = Run(WhichFunc, What)
End Function
```

(Calling this with `debug.print x` in the Immediate Window will give you a 2)

Comment: This code did help me to better understand the run method. While it was not exactly what I was looking for it was def a help. Thank you!

Comment: That's how these things go, sometimes. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I don't see how this has anything at all to do with the original question, where the problem is entirely due to not distinguishing the two distinct ways one calls a Function vs. a Subroutine in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a method without braces, like:

```
Application.Run sFunctionName, sParam1
```